# Vuejs template not displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I followed this Vuejs video tutorial : https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/9?autoplay=true

My HTML seems like him (except his design) :

```
<div id="app">
  <message title="My Component title" body="Lorem ipsum dry"></message>
</div>
```

Then my vuejs code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>
<script>

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['${', '}']
    });

    Vue.component('message', {
        props: ['title', 'body'],
        template: `
            <article class="message">

                <div class="message-header">
                    ${title}
                </div>

                <div class="message-body">
                    ${body}
                </div>
            </article>
        `
    });

</script>
```

I changed Vuejs variable delimiters because it's a twig template file. 
Inspecting the source code in the browser,  the HTML code is not replaced by the code defined in the template...   I don't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your template using JavaScript template strings (`` ` ``).

You need to escape `${` in template strings, because they have specific meaning for them. Escape like: `\${`

Also, you need to declare the `delimiters` on the component itself.

JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/notocozepi/edit?html,js,output

Source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <message title="My Component title" body="Lorem ipsum dry"></message>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
        Vue.component('message', {
            props: ['title', 'body'],
            delimiters: ['${', '}'],
            template: `
            <article class="message">

                <div class="message-header">
                    \${title}
                </div>

                <div class="message-body">
                    \${body}
                </div>
            </article>
        `
        });

        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            delimiters: ['${', '}']
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

One last note: mind the order. The components must be defined *before* they are used.